# What is J0, J1, J2, J3 for on this Apple wireless card?

Tags: mac, hardware-failure

Upon a SSD drive swap I broke one of the cable connectors to this chip and I'm not sure what's broken now. Everything seems to be working. WIFI, Bluetooth and iSight Camera. I have a Macbook Pro 2011 Unibody (A1278). Anybody have some insight on this? Thanks.

https://www.ifixit.com/MacBook-Parts/MacBook-Pro-Unibody-Early-2011-Airport-Bluetooth-Board/IF161-083-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are antenna connectors. Though I'm not sure how one would break them.

Your wireless interfaces may now suffer from any combination of the following symptoms:

- Less range
- Less speed
- Less stability (against interference)

Comment: Must have yanked too hard and snapped one of the connectors. I'll have to order that part and get it replaced. Thanks!

Comment: @kevllar So you didn’t just disconnect the cable, right? Maybe the connector was faulty to begin with.

Comment: Oh no I definitely tore the cord. You can see the broken fibers..

Answer (score 0):

Yes antenna connections attached not to the WiFi transceiver module. I hope you didn’t put a drive in that slot?
Some good lighting, A magnifying glass or glasses helps a whole lot when working on computers.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).